# Bootstrap jumbotron background image extra space when shrinking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When shrinking my browser window and looking at the jumbotron, theres extra space that keeps expanding underneath the image.

It looks like this:

Normal 100% width
[image]

50% browser width:
[image]

20% browser width (mobile, the question marks are the expanding extra space):
[image]

The grey extra space expands and contracts as I resize my browser.

This is my jumbotron CSS;

```
    .jumbotron {

    background-image: url('Banner_responsive.jpg')!important;
    background-size: 100% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    padding-bottom: 17px !important;
    margin-bottom: -5px !important;

}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of all those `!important` flags, give your jumbotron a custom class and target that, like `.jumbotron.myclass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background-size property applies auto height when you use one-value syntax. Try this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ha2j3yk8/)**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: this is 100% 100% the right answer. Perfect! Thanks